# peoplesoft integration with twilio

Tags: twilio, peoplesoft

I am a peoplesoft developer on PT8.52. We are trying to integrate with twilio for SMS alerts through a batch process(Application engine). I was hoping they will provide WSDL and it will be a simple integration. Looks like that's not the case. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio uses a REST API which relies on HTTP requests. You can still use Peoplesoft with REST as far as I know. A quick lookup got me to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tibr/chapter.htm?File=tibr/htm/tibr12.htm).

Also have a look at this post to see how to [consume a REST webservice via PeopleCode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/task_UsingPeopleCodetoManageRESTServiceOperations-b48000.html).

The documentation for Twilio's REST API can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest). the basic idea is that if you can make HTTP requests, you should be able to use the API with no problems.

As always, come back here if you need any more help.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

REST web services do not have a WSDL, that is for XML / SOAP messaging.  REST APIs may sometimes include a swagger file, but even PeopleSoft doesnt support that.

You need to create a document object linked to a message object, create your service, operations, and handler code all manually.  Or you can do what I did and use an xml message and embed your json, there are some limitations with the way Oracle designed the document object.

If you have any specific questions about any of those steps I can help you out.

Here is an example of a REST service I did in an App Engine.  Notice the use of a CDATA section in the XML, this is where you put your JSON string.

```
/* LOGIN ********************************************************************************************/ 
Local Message &msg_Login_Request, &msg_Login_Response; 
Local Document &doc_Login_Request; 
Local integer &i, &j, &errCount; 
Local array of string &arrRows, &arrRow; 
Local string &url_CalendarList; 
Local boolean &nReturn; 
Local string &Exception; 

&msg_Login_Request = CreateMessage(Operation.MM_ADA_LOGIN_POST); 

/* TODO: USERNAME AND PASSWORD */ 
Local string &str_username = "MASKED"; 
Local string &str_password = "MASKED"; 

/* Build XML Document with the post string */ 
Local XmlDoc &inxml = CreateXmlDoc(""); 
Local XmlNode &rootNode = &inxml.CreateDocumentElement("data"); 
Local XmlNode &cdataNode = &rootNode.AddCDataSection("{username:'" | &str_username | "',password:'" | &str_password | "'}"); 
&rootNode.AddAttribute("psnonxml", "yes"); 
&msg_Login_Request.SetXmlDoc(&inxml); 


/* SET IBInfo Properties */ 
&msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.SyncServiceTimeout = 360000; 
&msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.ConnectorOverride = True; 
&msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.ConnectorName = "HTTPTARGET"; 
&msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.ConnectorClassName = "HttpTargetConnector"; 

/* SET HTTP HEADERS */ 
&nReturn = &msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("SSLProtocols", "TLSv1.2", %HttpHeader); 
&nReturn = &msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("Content-Type", "application/json; encoding= UTF-8", %HttpHeader); 

/* SET HTTP PROPERTIES */ 
&nReturn = &msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("SOAPUpContent", "N", %HttpProperty); 
&nReturn = &msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("Method", "POST", %HttpProperty); 
&nReturn = &msg_Login_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("URL", "https://theurl.com/path", %HttpProperty); 

&msg_Login_Response = %IntBroker.ConnectorRequest(&msg_Login_Request, True); 

If &msg_Login_Response.ResponseStatus = %IB_Status_Success Then 
   rem &Output = &msg_Login_Response.GetXmlDoc(); 
Else 
   &Exception = &msg_Login_Response.IBException.ToString(); 
End-If; 

/* TODO: LOGIN RESULT CHECK */ 
If True = True Then 

   /* CALENDAR LIST **************************************************************************************************/ 
   Local Message &msg_CalendarList_Request, &msg_CalendarList_Response; 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request = CreateMessage(Operation.MM_ADA_CALENDARLIST); 

   /* Build XML Document With the post string */ 
   Local XmlDoc &inxml_CalendarList = CreateXmlDoc(""); 
   Local XmlNode &rootNode_CalendarList = &inxml_CalendarList.CreateDocumentElement("data"); 
   Local XmlNode &cdataNode_CalendarList = &rootNode_CalendarList.AddCDataSection("{}"); 
   &rootNode_CalendarList.AddAttribute("psnonxml", "yes"); 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.SetXmlDoc(&inxml_CalendarList); 

   /* SET IBInfo Properties */ 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.SyncServiceTimeout = 360000; 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.ConnectorOverride = True; 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.ConnectorName = "HTTPTARGET"; 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.ConnectorClassName = "HttpTargetConnector"; 

   /* SET HTTP HEADERS */ 
   &nReturn = &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("SSLProtocols", "TLSv1.2", %HttpHeader); 
   &nReturn = &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("Content-Type", "application/json; encoding= UTF-8", %HttpHeader); 

   /* SET HTTP PROPERTIES */ 
   &nReturn = &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("SOAPUpContent", "N", %HttpProperty); 
   &nReturn = &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("Method", "GET", %HttpProperty); 
   &url_CalendarList = "https://hiddenurl/path"; 
   &url_CalendarList = &url_CalendarList | "?fields=ActivityName,SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.SectionMeeting.Section.Term.Siskey,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.SectionMeeting.ExamParentSectionMtg.SisKey,SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.SectionMeeting.Section.SisKey,SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.RoomConfiguration.Room.SisKey"; 
   &url_CalendarList = &url_CalendarList | "&filter=(ActivityTypeCode%3D%3D1%26%26SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.SectionMeeting.IsExam%3D%3D1%26%26SectionMeetInstanceByActivityId.SectionMeeting.Section.Term.Siskey%3D%3D%271153%27)"; 
   &url_CalendarList = &url_CalendarList | "&sortOrder=&limit=100000&view=JSON"; 

   &nReturn = &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("URL", &url_CalendarList, %HttpProperty); 

   /* Copy the login cookies to this request */ 
   &msg_CalendarList_Request.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.Cookies = &msg_Login_Response.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.Cookies; 

   /* Invoke the method */ 
   &msg_CalendarList_Response = %IntBroker.ConnectorRequest(&msg_CalendarList_Request, True); 

   If &msg_CalendarList_Response.ResponseStatus = %IB_Status_Success Then 
      rem &Output = &msg_CalendarList_Response.GetXmlDoc(); 
   Else 
      &Exception = &msg_CalendarList_Response.IBException.ToString(); 
   End-If; 

   rem MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "Output: " | &Output); 
   rem MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "EXCEPTION: " | &Exception); 

   /******************************************************* 
PARSE THE JSON STRING WITH RHINO 
*******************************************************/ 
   /* 
Local JavaObject &manager = CreateJavaObject("javax.script.ScriptEngineManager"); 
Local JavaObject &engine = &manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); 

&engine.put("json_string", "[""item1"", ""item2"", ""item3""]"); 

&str_jsFunction = GetHTMLText(HTML.MM_ADA_PARSE_JSON, &msg_CalendarList_Response.GetContentString()); 

&engine.eval(&str_jsFunction); 

REM ** Access the value of the JavaScript variable named result; 
Local string &result_text = &engine.get("result").toString(); 

MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "RESULT TEXT: " | &result_text); 
*/ 

   /* Clear the staging table */ 
   SQLExec("TRUNCATE TABLE PS_MM_ADA_JSON_IN"); 
   &errCount = 0; 

   Local string &strData = Substring(&msg_CalendarList_Response.GetContentString(), Find("""" | "data" | """" | ":", &msg_CalendarList_Response.GetContentString()) + 9, Len(&msg_CalendarList_Response.GetContentString())); 
   &arrRows = Split(&strData, "],["); 

   For &i = 1 To &arrRows.Len 
      /* Fix NULL values */ 
      &arrRows [&i] = Substitute(&arrRows [&i], "null", """" | "null" | """"); 
      /* Remove the trailing JSON */ 
      &arrRows [&i] = Substitute(&arrRows [&i], """" | "]]}", ""); 
      /* Split the comma separated values */ 
      &arrRow = Split(&arrRows [&i], """" | "," | """"); 
      /* Remove the leading double quote */ 
      &arrRow [1] = Substring(&arrRow [1], 2, Len(&arrRow [1])); 
      /* Remove the trailing double quote */ 
      &arrRow [7] = Substring(&arrRow [7], 1, Len(&arrRow [7]) - 1); 
      /* Prepare the Date Time values */ 
      &arrRow [3] = Substitute(&arrRow [3], "T", " "); 
      &arrRow [4] = Substitute(&arrRow [4], "T", " "); 
      /* Fix remaining NULL values */ 
      For &j = 1 To &arrRow.Len 
         If &arrRow [&j] = "null" Then 
            &arrRow [&j] = " "; 
         End-If; 
      End-For; 
      try 
         SQLExec("INSERT INTO PS_UC_ADA_JSON_IN VALUES(:1,:2,%DateTimeIn(:3),%DateTimeIn(:4),:5,:6,:7)", &arrRow [1], &arrRow [2], &arrRow [3], &arrRow [4], &arrRow [5], &arrRow [6], &arrRow [7]); 
      catch Exception &err 
         &errCount = &errCount + 1; 
         MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE = MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE | Char(10) | "EXCEPTION: " | &err.ToString() | Char(10); 
         MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE = MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE | &arrRow [1] | " , " | &arrRow [2] | " , " | &arrRow [3] | " , " | &arrRow [4] | " , " | &arrRow [5] | " , " | &arrRow [6] | " , " | &arrRow [7]; 
         MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE = MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE | Char(10); 
      end-try; 
   End-For; 

   MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE = "ERRORS: " | &errCount | Char(10) | MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE; 
Else 
   /* AUTHENTICATION FAILED */ 
   MM_ADA_TEST_WRK.LONGVALUE = "AUTHENTICATION FAILED."; 

End-If;
```